# How to add shadows to material properties in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

I studied about the topic of shadows in blender and found [this page](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shadows.html) from the manual. It states that blender needs to be in GLSL mode for this option to be available. How do I add shadows to material properties?

[image: cycles material nodes]

That is the material I want to add  shadows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those settings are for either Blender Internal rendering engine, or for the Blender Game Engine, displaying shadows in the viewport for Blender Cycles materials and shader is not currently supported.

Either switch rendering engines (on the pulldown menu that reads *Cyckes Render* in the header of the *Info Window* on the top blender screen) and rebuild your materials for the new render, if your priority is getting viewport shadows; or if you wish to remain with Cycles then use viewport rendered preview  (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>)

**Edit:** To achieve a shadowless material setup in cycles you can use a light path node to drive a mix shader between a glass and a transparent shader as illustrated bellow.

[image: Shadowless Cycles Material]

Comment: See this scene http://i.stack.imgur.com/0WHPN.jpg , my priority is to remove  shadows of water drops in this render without changing my renderer an tricks to do that in cycles?

Comment: You can use a light path node for that, check the updated answer above.

Comment: another way is to go under object data  ->cycles settings >ray visibility and uncheck  shadows for the can material  it works same as receive transparent option in game engine and blender render